# Using Talend - how do you capitalize dynamic month 'MMM' in output file name?

Tags: talend

I'm creating output files and using the following naming convention:

CH_"+TalendDate.getDate("MMM")+"_BdayVipEmail.txt"

Is there a way to format the 'MMM' to uppercase?  The resulting file name would be 'CH_JUN_BdayVipEmail.txt

Thanks!

Comment: do you solve? mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

use TalendDate.getDate("MMM").toUpperCase()